# Google Maps Infobox on Custom HTML Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get an infobox to open after clicking an overlay(custom HTML marker).

This map shows a typical marker and a customer HTML marker. When I click the typical marker, the infobox opens correctly. When I click the custom HTML marker, the infobox doesn't open with error msg: `TypeError: anchor.getPosition is not a function`. This relates to the incorrect parameters I'm passing to `infobox.open()`. It expects a marker, but since I'm clicking an overlay (custom HTML marker), the parameter passed is incorrect.

How can I adjust the `infobox.open()` function so that it accepts my overlay as a parameter?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

#map{
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<script src="....path/to/custom-html-markers-google-maps.js"></script>
<script>

var infobox = new InfoBox({
    disableAutoPan: false,
    maxWidth: 300,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-75, -70),
    zIndex: null,
    boxStyle: {width: '150px'},
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(15, 50)
});


function initialize() {

    var loc =        new google.maps.LatLng(-33.89, 151.26);
    var locMarker =  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.89, 151.23);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: loc,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    //This works FINE.. It sets the marker and infobox listener
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: locMarker,
        visible: true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infobox.setContent('<div style="background-color:yellow">This is<br>an infobox.</div>');
        infobox.open(map, this);
    });


    //Overlay from: http://humaan.com/custom-html-markers-google-maps/
    var overlay = new CustomMarker(loc, map, {marker_id: '123'});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Part of Custom HTML Marker script:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function(event) {

    infobox.setContent('<div style="background-color:yellow">Hi there</div>');
    infobox.open(map, this);  //*******THIS IS THE PROBLEM********

    google.maps.event.trigger(self, "click");
});
```

My problem is `infobox.open(map, this);` is expecting a marker and I give it the "div". How can I adjust this function so that it accepts my div?

Full script: http://humaan.com/custom-html-markers-google-maps/

Answer (score 1):

To use anything as an anchor for a marker, it needs to expose a latLng position property and an optional anchorPoint property.

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindow):

> **open(map?:Map|StreetViewPanorama, anchor?:MVCObject)**
>
> Return Value:  None
>
> Opens this InfoWindow on the given map. Optionally, an InfoWindow can be associated with an anchor. **In the core API, the only anchor is the Marker class. However, an anchor can be any MVCObject that exposes a LatLng position property and optionally a Point anchorPoint property for calculating the pixelOffset (see InfoWindowOptions). The anchorPoint is the offset from the anchor's position to the tip of the InfoWindow.**

Comment: Thanks, I revised the LatLng position and map variables that are carried into the function.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't carrying the correct **loc**(lat/lng) and **map** into the function call.

Here is the revised listener:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function(event) {

    var map =   self.getMap();
    var loc =   self.latlng;

    infobox.setContent('<div style="background-color:yellow">Hi there</div>');
    infobox.openRevised(map, this, loc);

    google.maps.event.trigger(self, "click");
});
```

Here is the revised `infobox.open()` function:

```
InfoBox.prototype.openRevised = function (map, anchor, loc) {

    if (anchor) {

        this.position_ = loc;
    }

    this.setMap(map);
};
```